# creating visual force page

Tags: visualforce

[image]I want to create visual force page with all the fields shown in image. i have done till class field im stuckup in joining date and lookup tution class.

here is my code.
please help me with this.

```
              </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                      <apex:outputLabel value="FirstName"/>
                     <apex:inputText value="{!FirstName}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                          <apex:outputLabel value="LastName"/>
                          <apex:inputText value="{!LastName}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                          <apex:outputLabel value="Age"/>
                          <apex:inputText value="{!Age}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                      <apex:outputLabel value="Classs"/>
                          <apex:selectList size="1">
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="10" itemValue="10"/>
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="12" itemValue="12"/>
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="11" itemValue="11"/>
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="9" itemValue="9"/>
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="8" itemValue="8"/>
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="7" itemValue="7"/>
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="6" itemValue="6"/>
                              <apex:selectOption itemLabel="5" itemValue="5"/>
                          </apex:selectList>

                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
           </apex:form>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If your object had a lookup field to another object then 'apex:inputField ' would render as a lookup field automatically. The only thing is, you need to declare a property instance variable in the vf page controller

see the below example :
Controller

```
  public class MyTestController {

      public Contact contact {get;set;}
      public MyTestController () {
          contact = new Contact();
     }

}
```

VF

```
<apex:inputField id="Account" value="{!contact.AccountId}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has a standard component `<apex:input>` which can help you for this Date field.
This component has a Type attribute to accept date.

In VF Page: ***Mention docType in ApexPage attribute

```
<apex:page controller="datePicker" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:form >    
    JoiningDate: <apex:input type="date" value="{!datename}"/>
</apex:form>
```

In Apex:

```
public Date JoiningDate{get;set;}
```

Does all these fields belong to Student Object or Is it just for a screenshot you took this pic?

If all these fields belongs to an Object, you can refer these fields in a VF Page as:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!Object.FirstName]" />
<apex:inputText value="{!Object.LastName]" />
<apex:inputText value="{!Object.Age]" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Object.Class]" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Object.JoiningDate]" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Object.Tutionclass]" />
```

Comment: input type date is not working

Comment: Please add docType="html-5.0" in Apex Page attribute